# Xen DomO Has Network But DomU Does Not

Tags: networking, bridge, xen, netplan

My server lost power last night so was abruptly shut down. Bringing it back up this morning my xen dom0 can connect to network, but my domU cannot. Tried full reboots of Dom0 and DomU. Only DomU on hypervisor so not able to compare DomUs to determine if root cause is Dom0 or U. I haven't done any changes to my configuration in a couple years so I'm a bit stumped and could use some help getting this back up.

**Error**

```
domU:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
```

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.86.100 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.86.100 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.86.100 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.86.100 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4037ms
pipe 3
```

**Configs:**

```
domU:~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [192.168.86.100/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.86.1 
      nameservers:
          addresses: [1.1.1.1]
```

---

```
domU:~$ ip route
```

```
default via 192.168.86.1 dev eth0 proto static 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-7fb8d047dcba proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-e7cdb61e5c17 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-f11060eb56f3 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-075b602ce9f7 proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 linkdown 
172.22.0.0/16 dev br-e812d3a26476 proto kernel scope link src 172.22.0.1 
172.23.0.0/16 dev br-d1c3ee2c4f77 proto kernel scope link src 172.23.0.1 
172.24.0.0/16 dev br-aa973d061ea7 proto kernel scope link src 172.24.0.1 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-d174c2aa0e7d proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 
172.26.0.0/16 dev br-ad2326a15232 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1 linkdown 
172.27.0.0/16 dev br-9a95e94769ef proto kernel scope link src 172.27.0.1 
172.28.0.0/16 dev br-565bcc95223a proto kernel scope link src 172.28.0.1 linkdown 
172.29.0.0/16 dev br-6c03714dca11 proto kernel scope link src 172.29.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.86.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.86.100
```

---

```
dom0:~$ cat /etc/netplan/config.yaml
```

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd

  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bridges:
    xenbr0:
      interfaces: [enp0s25]
      addresses: [192.168.86.99/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.86.1
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

---

```
dom0:~$ ip addr show
```

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master xenbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:90:96:d3:41:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: xenbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:90:96:d3:41:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.86.99/24 brd 192.168.86.255 scope global xenbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9a90:96ff:fed3:41f5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vif1.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master xenbr0 state UP group default qlen 32
    link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

```
dom0:~$ brctl show
```

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
xenbr0      8000.989096d341f5   yes     enp0s25
                                        vif1.0
```

---

```
dom0:~$ sudo xl network-list domU
```

```
Idx BE Mac Addr.         handle state evt-ch   tx-/rx-ring-ref BE-path                       
0   0  00:16:3e:f5:45:18     0     4     -1  4096/4097        /local/domain/0/backend/vif/1/0
```

---

```
dom0 ~$ cat /etc/xen/domainU.cfg
```

```
...
#  Networking
#
vif         = [ 'ip=192.168.86.100 ,mac=00:16:3E:F5:45:18, bridge=xenbr0' ]
...
```

Xen Version ***4.11***
Dom0 OS: Ubuntu 18.04
DomU OS: Debian 10.13

Comment: What happens when you remove the ip from domainU.cfg and then restart the DomU?

Comment: @Nils I shutdown dom U >> removed ip >> created dom U but same error persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing the bug described here:
[5.15.0-58.64 breaks xen bridge networking (pvh domU)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2002889)

tl;dr from that bug report is apparently this is a regresion related to a security fix. There's a fix currently being tested. The kernel version which has the potential fix is 5.15.0-**66**

#### To solve:

I subscribed to pre-releases to get the most up-to-date kernel.

1. Add `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-proposed main` to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` (note to other users affected: replace "jammy" with your current distro if you're using a different ubuntu version)
2. `apt-get update`
3. `apt-get full-upgrade` *

- Note that `apt full-upgrade` is necessary here, not simply `apt upgrade`, as many users are in the habit of typing. The full-upgrade portion of the command will instruct Ubuntu to also upgrade the system kernel. You will then need to reboot the system in order to utilize the new kernel.

Again the target version for the fix is 5.15.0.-66. When I ran `full-upgrade` I saw the message

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
linux-headers-5.15.0-66 linux-headers-5.15.0-66-generic linux-modules- 
extra-5.15.0-66-generic
```

After a reboot,
`uname -r` returns
`5.15.0.-66-generic`

and both Dom0 and DomU were able to connect to network as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your DomU instance is not able to connect to the internet. To diagnose the issue, we need to look into the network configurations for both Dom0 and DomU.

From your configuration, it seems that the Dom0 is connected to the network and has assigned the IP address of 192.168.86.99 with a gateway of 192.168.86.1. However, the DomU is not able to reach the default gateway.

One possible issue could be a misconfigured netplan configuration file in the DomU, as indicated in the file "/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml". Check if the gateway is reachable and make sure the network settings in the configuration file are correct. Additionally, make sure that the network interface eth0 is up and running.

You can also try to verify the network connectivity by performing a simple ping test from DomU to the gateway (192.168.86.1) and the default nameserver (1.1.1.1).

Another possible issue could be related to the routing table. Check the routing table for any incorrect or missing routes. If you find any issues, try to correct them.

Finally, it is also a good idea to check if there are any firewall rules or network security policies that are blocking the network traffic from the DomU.